# When do I update the Git repo package.json/version release?

Tags: version-control, git, github, semantic-versioning

I am starting to get into versions/releases more now with Git and wanted to know if the structure I am doing now is correct.

Right now, there is typically a few **feature branches**. A few commits from those then get merged into the **develop branch** for review.

After that I merge them into the **master** and the package.json version gets bumped up depending if it's a major, minor or patch and then a new release is created.

Should the package.json version be getting updated every commit though? or can I do this in stages with commits that I want to push towards a specific version.

Right now this is just a simple project, but I want to know if this is the correct workflow and what other best practices are for proper version numbering in a package/repository.

Comment: This depends a lot on the language and framework you're using as well as your downstream process. E.g., it sounds like you're using node.js, which has community-driven conventions about when to bump versions. Additionally, the answers will differ depending on if you're releasing publicly (e.g., to npm) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are working with JavaScript (Node.js).

The workflow you have described appears correct. When you update `package.json` is when you have something new to release. If this is every commit then yes be it so, otherwise when changes get merged into master for a new release, its the correct time to up the package version.

The new version number of the `package.json` signals the users of the package that there are new, usable, released changes in the package made by the package maintainer(s).

- commit number/id/hash - changes every time you have a new commit
- build number - ups every time you build your code, usually with one or more commits in it (usually your continuous integration will give you this)
- package version - ups every time you ship new changes to users of the package, usually after a stable build.